# trying to print dictionary key pair

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to print from a dictionary to populate another script.  I keep getting "unexpected character after line continuation character".  I dont know why

```
mydic = {"printer1": "printserver1", "printer2": "printserver2"}

for key in mydic.keys():
  print ("For /F \"Tokens=4 delims=\\\" %%I In ('reg query HKCU\\Printers\\Connections       ^|find /I \"" + key + "\"') Do If \"%%I\"==\",,"+ mydic[key] +"," + key + "\" goto :REMOVE" + \n + "goto :SKIP" + \n + ":REMOVE" + \n + "RUNDLL32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n \\\\"+ mydic[key] +"\\" + key + " /dn" + \n + ":SKIP")
```

Comment: You need to put \n in quotes

Comment: But your main problem is that your code doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Iterating over the dictionary iterates over its keys, so there's no need to call `keys()` explicitly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplify this so it's not all one line, more readable and newlines are automatically part of the string by using multi-line strings:

```
mydic = {"printer1": "printserver1", "printer2": "printserver2"}

template = r"""
FOR /F in blah blah blah
    do something with {key}
    with the value of {value}
    blah blah blah
END FOR
"""

for key, value in mydic.iteritems():
    print template.format(key=key, value=value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the `\n` newlines part of the string:

```
print ("For /F \"Tokens=4 delims=\\\" %%I In ('reg query HKCU\\Printers\\Connections       ^|find /I \"" +
       key + "\"') Do If \"%%I\"==\",," + mydic[key] + "," + key + 
       "\" goto :REMOVE\ngoto :SKIP\n:REMOVERUNDLL32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n \\\" +
       mydic[key] +"\\" + key + " /dn\n:SKIP")
```

You really want to use some [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) here, together with a triple-quoted raw string to cut down on all those backslashes:

```
template = r"""For /F "Tokens=4 delims=\" %%I In ('reg query HKCU\Printers\Connections       ^|find /I "{0}"') Do If "%%I"==",,"{1},{0}" goto :REMOVE
goto :SKIP
:REMOVERUNDLL32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n \{1}\{0} /dn
:SKIP"""

for key in mydic:
    print(template.format(key, mydic[key]))
```